# royalSlider using ajax to load slides

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm sure this is to do with variable scope, but I can seem to work it out. I'm trying to load slide into the royalSlider plugin using the following code:

```
var firstItem = true;
for(var i=0; i<vehIds.length; i++){

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/proxy/vehicleDetails.aspx?vehId=" + vehIds[i],
    dateType: "html",
    success: function(html) {

        if(firstItem){
            firstItem = false;
            $('#stockSlider').append(html);

            var mainSlider = $('#stockSlider').royalSlider({
                loop: false,
                autoPlay: {
                    enabled: true,
                    pauseOnHover: true,
                    delay: 5500
                }
            }).data('royalSlider');
        } else {
            mainSlider.appendSlide(html);
        }

    },
    complete: function() {}
    }).done(function(){}); // End of Ajax call
}
```

The first item loads fine, but subsequent items throw the following error in console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendSlide' of undefined
```

Like I say I'm pretty sure it's a skope issue, but could be wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Declare `var mainSlider;` outside of `for` loop and in success callback, use: `mainSlider = $('#stockSlider').royalSlider({...});`. Does it fix it? In fact, do like for `firstItem`

Comment: I'm sure I tried that, but I've just tried it again and it worked. God-like. Big thanks. If you want to put it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks again.